# Three.ObjectLoader: can't load

Tags: javascript, three.js

I first time to use Three js, and me need load model from JSON file. And i use for it THREE.ObjectLoader, but give this error. What i doing wrong? And how i can do this?
I have no other files like gltf, only JSON format.
Thanks for help!!

```
      let loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
      loader.load(
        'adapters/glove/new_hand.json',
        function (obj) {
          // Add the loaded object to the scene
          scene.add(obj);
        },

        // onProgress callback
        function (xhr) {
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded');
        },

        // onError callback
        function (err) {
          console.error('An error happened');
        }
      );
```

[image]

that new_hand.json

[image]

Comment: The first param of ObjectLoader.load is Resource URL. Try server URL.

Comment: That error indicates that the file exists but isn't properly formatted as [JSON Object/Scene format](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Object-Scene-format-4).

Comment: if i using JSON Object/Scene format this example, i get this error THREE:ObjectLoader: Can't parse adapters/glove/new_hand.json. Unexpected token / in JSON at position 467

Comment: Yes, some of those examples have comments in them (lines starting with `//`) which aren't valid JSON. If you remove them, then they will at least be parsed.

Comment: Based on the name of the file (`new_hand.json`) I suspect you may be trying to load something like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keepevets/threejshand/master/new_hand.json). If so, the error is related to there not being an appropriate `metadata` attribute in the loaded JSON.

Comment: Yep, my json look like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keepevets/threejshand/master/new_hand.json , but what metadata me need? I edit my question, add new_hand.json file.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact requirements for version 4 of the format, but my feeling is that you'll have to convert the file over yourself; a brief look for converters between the versions hasn't turned anything up.

Comment: Okey, thanks for hint.